# How to get only matching result from JSON output using python?

Tags: python, selenium, scripting, output

I have written a script in selenium python,I am stuck at a point where I want to make a get call to http://localhost:0000/v1/s3status ,and the output will be something like shown in the image attached.[Attached output of get call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syqPN.png)

```
datasources= requests.get("http://localhost:0000/v1/s3status")
```

I am looking for a solution where I just need the script output for only specific  values, stages:{},validated:{},failed:{}

So output of python script should be something like :

```
Datasources of Staged :{Whatever the result will be inside}
Datasources of Failed :{Whatever the result will be inside} 
Datasouces of Validated :{Whatever the result will be inside}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image(s). Please include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to convert your request to json.

```
import json
import requests

datasources= requests.get("http://localhost:0000/v1/s3status").json()

print("Staged : {}".format(datasources['staged']))
print("Failed : {}".format(datasources['failed']))
print("Validated : {}".format(datasources['validated']))
```